# python script send signal to another running python script on another workstation on same network

Tags: python

I have an already running python application on a workstation 1 on the network. On workstation 2 on the same network I want to run another python application which sends a signal to the workstation 1 python application which is already running, just like if I was pressing a button on workstation 1, triggering a function. The workstations are a mix on Windows and OSX. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use sockets, the examples here are exactly what you're looking for:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example